# Sort output of grep by file size? (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to grep for a certain string, in a certain directory. Then I want to sort the files by size (number of bytes would be fine). The files are .php files, though I don't think other non-php files would have the string I'm looking for. How do I do this?

I got the grep part:

`grep -rl "foostring" ~/myfolder`

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q doesn't have any code that we can help fix. But we don't want to do your programming work for you, so please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping through the files and use `wc -c` to show the file size in bytes.

```
for f in ~/myfolder/*.php; do       ##: Loop through the *.php files only.
  size=$(wc -c < "$f")              ##: Save the file size in a variables.
  if grep -Fq foostring "$f"; then  ##: -F means fixed strings and -q means quiet/silent nothing to output to stdout.
    printf 'file [%s] has [%d] size.\n' "$f" "$size"  ##: Print a fancy format using printf.
  fi
done
```